# Rails app not reflecting recent changes at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

I have a rails(Rails 3.2.12, ruby 1.9.3p547) app running on AWS ubuntu cloud server, with nginx as app server and unicorn as reverse proxy server.
I have made few changes in the view file but those changes are not reflecting on browser. Code is currently live ("env=production")

> I tried

```
sudo service my_app restart
[sudo] password for me:
Shutting down my_app: Starting my_app: Already running
                                                           [  OK  ]
$  sudo service nginx restart
Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
$
```

but still got no help its still rendering the previous one. I tried commenting the whole controller file for the same view but still the app is not showing any error. **I have confirmed that the app is running from the same folder in which I am making changes**

I got stuck at this point please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: which files you made changes in?

Comment: *app/views/reports/show.html.haml*

Comment: How do you usually deploy your app? Why do you need to make this change directly on your production environment? Did you try to `stop` and `start` the unicorn and nginx instead of calling `restart` (I know about some setups in which restart doesn't work as expected).

Comment: I tried stop and start as well.

Comment: How did you check and confirm the folder is actually used by the running application?

Comment: confirmed it from nginx config file

Comment: I suppose you are using phusion passenger in production mood.So try `cd into your project folder` then run `touch tmp/restart.txt` .Now you should have changes you made.

Comment: I wish this could have helped but its not working at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue resolved with the help of the comments which gave me the idea.
located the **.pid** file in *tmp/pids/unicorn.pid* which was having the current process id

```
$ kill -QUIT 5454 #process id
```

and then again started the unicorn service and nginx service, and changes started reflecting